# how to create view for chatting like facebook or whatsapp

Tags: iphone, ios4, uiview, chat

I am creating chat application and in that I don't know how to create a view like facebook or gtalk chat applicatons.

Like sender name and message on left and receiver name and message on right side of the view.

If any sample code please let me know.

thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Check out `SSMessagesViewController` on https://github.com/samsoffes/ssmessagesviewcontroller

Answer (score 0):

a good one is JSQMessagesViewController. You can find the code and documentation at: http://www.jessesquires.com/JSQMessagesViewController/